# "This" in parameter function

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

There is the following code:

```
@rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', @stopProcessing)

stopProcessing: ->
  @processCount--
  @processCount = 0 if @processCount <= 0
```

When I execute this code it doesn't work properly, because @processCount doesn't change. I understand why it goes - "this" in @rootScope.$on link to @rootScope, and not for my object(where I execute $on and where I store stopProcessing function). How can I fix it in the right way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not to be an ass, but because I simply AM one... `if @processCount < 0`, otherwise, why waste an operation on a redundant assignment.

Comment: And.. while I'm in one of those moods... make it a one liner: `@processCount = 0 if --@processCount < 0`

Comment: You are right man, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in coffeescript if you want `this` stick to declaration context (to object in which you declare a callback) you should use fat arrow (`=>`) in stopProcessing declaration.

```
stopProcessing: =>
  @processCount--
  @processCount = 0 if @processCount <= 0
```